# SQL error 21000 when trying to lookup a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to SQL, sorry if this is trivial.

I have 2 tables, film and inventory, they share a film_id column and what I would like is a 3 columns table taking 2 columns from film (film_id, title) and 1 from inventory (store_id). The inventory table also contains film_id. This is my code :

```
select 
e.film_id,
e.title, 
(select v.store_id from inventory v where e.film_id = v.film_id)
from film e
```

I get a SQL error 21000
I know it could be solved with a join but I am trying to experiment in some sort of alternative vlookup way.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Always include the comete error message . Also most problem with correlated subqueries are that more than one row is returned

Comment: Databases aren't Excel sheets. There's no VLOOKUP in relational databases. What you wrote will fail if there's more than one match. What *do* you want to happen if there are multiple matches? Return the first? Last? A random one?

Comment: As for alternatives, the database doesn't execute the SQL text you provide. It parses it into an execution plan and optimizes it depending on the field types, indexes and data statistics - no point in using an index if all field values are the same after all. Multiple logically equivalent queries can end up producing the same execution plan

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your inventory table has multiple stores where this film is being found.
In this case, you have the following options:

- Use a join, this will give multiple rows for each combination of store and film
- Use an aggregate to combine the results, for example with STRING_AGG.